# Java Spring MVC stateless-to-stateful handover

Tags: java, model-view-controller, oop, spring

Although I have tagged this as a java/spring question it can be easily asked of any mvc framework with stateless controllers. I know rails uses simple stateless controllers for instance so perhaps you guys know how to best solve this problem. I can best describe the problem with java/spring mvc which is the implementation  - forgive the java jargon.

**The issue**

We are having trouble coming up with a satisfactory way of performing stateless-to-stateful handover in spring mvc. 
In essence given a structure like:

Model: `Unit`
With the states: withdrawn, available, unavailable
And the operations: `getOutline()` and `getHelp()`

Controller: `UnitController` 
with operations: `displayOutline()` and `displayHelp()`

We need a way to check the state of the unit before we execute the operation `displayOutline()` (because the unit itself may be withdrawn and so the user should be forwarded to a withdrawn page).

***We have tried to do this a number of ways including:***

**The dead simple way (any language)**

All methods in the controller that require an ‘available’ state unit call a method isAvailable() in the first line of its implementation. Obviously there lots of replication here, it reeks.

**The AOP way (Java specific)**

An @Around advice can be created called UnitAccess which does the check and reroutes the control flow (i.e. instead of calling proceed() which would invoke the underlying method it calls another method on the controller). This seems like a hack and not really what AOP if for, it does remove the replication but adds complexity and reduces transparency.

**An Interceptor (Provided by servlet architecture but probably doable in other frameworks)**

Which checks the unit state and essentially changes the actual URL call. Again this does not seem right. We don’t like the idea of invoking model logic before getting to a controller.

***We have thought about***

**Command Pattern**

Creating a command pattern structure which (with the use of inheritance) can return a withdrawn view or valid displayOutline view. As the execute method will perform the checks in a `super()`call and the specific logic inside the concrete commands. Ie creating a object structure like

```
DisplayOutlineCommand extends UnitCommand

    public void execute(){
        super();
        // must be ok, perform getOutline()
    }
```

**And finally, using a custom Exception**

Calling `getAvailableUnit()` on a service level object which will do the checks for availability, etc before returning the unit. If the unit is withdrawn then it will throw a UnitWithdrawnException which could be caught by the servlet and handled by returning an appropriate view. Were still not convinced. We  are also not hot on the idea of using an exception for normal flow control.

Are we missing something? Is there an easy way to do this under spring/another stateless controller framework?

Comment: Reflecting on using AOP: We don't think this is the right place for it as we generally feel crosscutting concerns should not 'fiddle' with the primary function of the class/method it is used. 'logging' or 'transaction management' are great uses for AOP as they essentially decorate without altering the context. A controller's main function is to control flow, using AOP to mess with the flow within a controller just does not seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but why should a user come to the controller if the Unit is withdrawn?

I would argue it is best to ensure that normally pages don't link to a controller that require the Unit to be 'OK', if that Unit is not 'OK'.
If the state of the Unit changes between the time the referring page is rendered and the actual call comes in to the controller (it is not longer 'OK'), then the use of an exception to handle that event seems perfectly fine to me (like having an exception when an optimistic locking error occurs).

Comment: Thanks Fried, I voted you up for your perspective but i cant give you the 'tick'. Basically I have come to the conclusion that stateful controllers are too hard. No-one seems to be using them in the real world. Instead devs opt for stateless controllers and store state in a httpsession object or similiar. Large companies seem to favor this approach which allows them to scale better. I would still love to hear others ideas on this problem however, Its called a number of things out there, the name i like most is throw-away controllers (because their lifecycle is bound to the request scope)

Comment: FYI, We eventually went for the exception method in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you haven't described the whole problem, but why not put the check in `displayOutline()` itself? perhaps route to a `displayOutlineOrHelp()` method, which looks essentially like

```
ModelAndView displayOutlineOrHelp(...)  {
    Unit unit = ... //code to get the unit the request refers to

    return unit.isAvailable() ? displayOutline(...) : displayHelp(...);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its a bit of a miss. displayOutline() and  displayHelp() are different methods with completely different views. An example url for either maybe app/unit/outline and /app/unit/help. The point is both require a unit which is in a status of 'ok'. Something like 20 of our view methods require a unit to be 'ok'. We could add a method call (method 1) but it seems more like a crosscutting concern (AOP - method 2) but it does not seem like the right solution. Ideally we are looking for a feature that is coherent with the standard oo metaphors without adding complexity.

Comment: Ah - I see - I misunderstood the question. I would say that AOP is the way to do it - this is of course doable with pure OOP, but it needs more work that way.